weird PointCloud2 msg when retrieved immediatly after trajectory execution
The point cloud data is weird when immediately retrieved from /camera/depth_registered/points. https://imgur.com/a/tYimz7t
But the end factor is indeed moved to the right spot before the point cloud retrieve.
And i have to wait for 1-2 seconds, then i can get the normal point cloud.
What could possibly cause this to happen?
EDIT: I found changing update_rate of the sensor in urdf can reduce the time needed for sleep. 15hz should sleep at least 1s, and 240hz and higher, sleep time lower than 1s can give situation a relief but still.
which means i can not avoid time.sleep this way, is there any other thing related to this?
gz stats says real time is ahead of sim time for 1s, does this has anything to do with the situation?

Have you propertly told all your ros nodes to use the simulation clock?

@Mike973 thanks, i try to directly run with --ros-args use_sim_time:=true.
Now the point clouds can not be seen in rviz...

@Mike973 I managed to fix the rviz issue now. and i'm sure every thing is set to use_sim_time=true. the problem still exist.

Are you using a real depth camera, or is it a simulated depth camera?

@Mike973 simulated depth camera, i'm facing this issue in gazebo.
And when i connect directly to gazebo point cloud topic inside rviz, it's working with no problem, i think maybe problem is about the transform using tf in my code.

@Mike973 Sorry it's not tf issue in my code, it would seem that the point cloud 2 msg header time is 1-2 seconds slower than the sim time in gazebo, what can i do with this.
for example the machine moved into position in 00:00:27, but the msg header time duration is 26
